# Implement theme as layout

Tags: go, themes, hugo, go-html-template

I'm looking for implementing [Hugo's HUGRID theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/hugrid/) as an additional layout for my blog (currently using [Cactus-plus theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/hugo-theme-cactus-plus/)), but I know almost nothing about Hugo templating. Should I try to code it as a layout or can I use the `HUGRID` theme inside `cactus-plus` theme for specific pages?

Comment: As this doesn't seem to be a software development question, you might have better luck asking this of the [Hugo community](https://discourse.gohugo.io/).

Comment: Sure, thanks @Adrian!